# Read all XML child nodes of each specific node

Tags: c#, linq

I need to read all the `Child Nodes` of my `<Imovel>` tag, the problem is that I has more than 1 (one) `<Imovel>` tag in my XML file, and the difference between each `<Imovel>` tag is an attribute called ID.

This is an example

```
<Imoveis>
   <Imovel id="555">
      <DateImovel>2012-01-01 00:00:00.000</DateImovel>
      <Pictures>
          <Picture>
              <Path>hhhhh</Path>
          </Picture>
      </Pictures>
      // Here comes a lot of another tags
   </Imovel>
   <Imovel id="777">
      <DateImovel>2012-01-01 00:00:00.000</DateImovel>
      <Pictures>
          <Picture>
              <Path>tttt</Path>
          </Picture>
      </Pictures>
      // Here comes a lot of another tags
   </Imovel>
</Imoveis>
```

I need read all tags of each `<Imovel>` tag, and in the end of each validation that I do in my `<Imovel>` tag I need to do another validation.

So, I think I need to do 2 (two) `foreach` or a `for` and a `foreach`, I don't understand very well about `LINQ` but follow my sample

```
XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(file);
XDocument doc2 = XDocument.Load(rdr);
ValidaCampos valida = new ValidaCampos();

//// Here I Count the number of `<Imovel>` tags exist in my XML File                        
for (int i = 1; i <= doc2.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name == "Imovel").Count(); i++)
{
    //// Get the ID attribute that exist in my `<Imovel>` tag
    id = doc2.Root.Descendants().ElementAt(0).Attribute("id").Value;

    foreach (var element in doc2.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Parent.Attribute("id").Value == id))
    {
       String name = element.Name.LocalName;
       String value = element.Value;
    }
}
```

But doesn't work very well, in my `foreach` statement because my `<Picture>` tag, her parent tag don't has an ID attribute.

Somebody can help me to do this method ?

Comment: `But doesn't work very well, in my foreach statement.` can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Yes, this is becuse the parent of my `<Picture>` tag don't has a ID attribute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do this with two foreach statements:

```
foreach(var imovel in doc2.Root.Descendants("Imovel"))
{
  //Do something with the Imovel node
  foreach(var children in imovel.Descendants())
  {
     //Do something with the child nodes of Imovel.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. System.Xml.XPath will add xpath selectors to XElement. Finding elements is much quicker and simpler with xpath.

You don't need XmlReader & XDocument to load the file.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("test.xml");

foreach (XElement imovel in root.XPathSelectElements("//Imovel"))
{
  foreach (var children in imovel.Descendants())
  {
     String name = children.Name.LocalName;
     String value = children.Value;

     Console.WriteLine("Name:{0}, Value:{1}", name, value);
  }

   //use relative xpath to find a child element
   XElement picturePath = imovel.XPathSelectElement(".//Pictures/Picture/Path");
   Console.WriteLine("Picture Path:{0}", picturePath.Value);
}
```

please include

```
System.Xml.XPath;
```